# Integer calculation not working as expected

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.H>
void main()
{
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i,h;
    float p;
    char A[10];
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the name\n");
    gets(A);
    printf("Enter the ENG marks\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the HIN marks\n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("Enter the MAR marks\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("Enter the MAT marks\n");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    printf("Enter the SCI marks\n");
    scanf("%d",&e);
    printf("Enter the S.S marks\n");
    scanf("%d",&f);
    g=a+b+c+d+e+f;
    p=(g*100)/600; // <<-----
    printf("NAME\t ENG\t HIN\t MAR\t MAT\t SCI\t S.S\t TOTAL\t PERCENTAGE\n");
    printf("%s\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %d\t %f\n",A,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,p);
    getch();
}
```

The program works fine except for the line marked. What's the problem with it?

Comment: Why don't you explain what you're currently seeing, and what you *expect* to see?

Comment: Probably you want to store a floating point value in `h`, but its type is `int`?

Comment: Those variable names are horrible.

Comment: apart from the problems, your code lacks too much spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to float before division

```
h=((float)g)/600;
```

Comment: or say 600.0; less characters, saves on electrons.

Answer (score 2):

This is truncating to an integer:

```
 p=(g*100)/600;
```

Change that to

```
 p=(g*100)/600.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since **h** is declared as an `int`, the line

```
h=(g/600);
```

will use integer division, not floating point division.  Basically, this means that everything beyond the decimal point will be ignored.  For example, giving the example `450/600`, floating point division would give you `0.75`, whereas integer division would give you `0`.

The subsequent line

```
p=(h*100);
```

takes this stored value of **h**, in this case `0`, and multiplies it by *100*.  Which is still `0`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a **lot** of problems in this code.

The percentage isn't being computed correctly because you're using integer math for the division; for example, if `g` is 500, the result of `g/600` would be 0, which gets assigned to `h` (also an integer).

There are several approaches:

1. Change the types of `a` through `h` from `int` to `float` or `double` (and change the corresponding conversion specifiers from `%d` to `%f` in the `printf` and `scanf` calls);
2. Cast `g` as a float before dividing by 600, *or* divide g by 600.0 (`h` will still need to be typed as a float, or you can skip the that step and simply write `p = ((float) g / 600) * 100.0;`

As far as everything else:

1. In a hosted implementation, `main` returns `int`, not `void`.  Unless your compiler documentation specifically says that `void main()` is supported, use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` instead, otherwise you are invoking undefined behavior;
2. **NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER NEVER** use `gets()`; it *will* introduce a point of failure in your program.  It was officially deprecated with C99, and is expected to be gone from the next version of the standard.  Use `fgets()` instead.